# unable delete temporany file with Upload Ajax and http task goes to 99%

Tags: ajax, upload, xpages, xpages-ssjs

Hi I have used this custom control
[Xpages Async Multi File Uploader Custom Control](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=Xpages%20Async%20Multi%20File%20Uploader%20Custom%20Control)
it works well, but after some tests we noticed that the temporary files (named __xspxxx) saved in a temporary folder \notes68787\xspupload are not deleted after the successfull upload.
The real problem is that after some uploads the nhttp task used CPU goes up to 50% and after one more upload goes on 100%.

We are in 8.5.3FP4 windows 2003 x64 environment.

have someone any suggestion?

Comment: Seems the code hangs http threads. Run NSD (keep server running) and look for stacktraces of frozen threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem: seem the ACL settings for Anonymous.
Before I have set it to Reader access and the CPU will go to 99%...

After I have change the Anonymous level to Depositor (write,public document) and work well..

Tnx you very much

P.S. I have changed the renamed line into SSJS to force a Delete ___xsp* temporany files and work very very well..

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce that problem. Can you try it on a Domino 9.0 environment? Or if you remove FP4 (FP0), do you still have problems?